# egrep output is showing symbols

Tags: unix, grep

My `egrep` output is showing symbols.

Command:

```
egrep "acsslc|adl04085|aprsvq0|brymfghp4|brymkt02|brymkthp4|ccenaq7|davagemaq0|davb031|davipa1|davipa10042|moxipra20024|mxawhse" /home/pandapx/prd_det_ROT.d
```

Output:

```
"acsslcL" "" "1o8d2e64F0p10h12v3T3G" "" "1o8d2e64F0p16.66h8.5v0T3G" "" "" "" 68 10 "" "HP L" yes "lp -s -onb -dacsslc" "
" "" "" "" "" "" 0 no ""
"acsslcP" "HP 4SI/5SI" "
0OU0p10h12v0s0b3T66P2E7.8689C66F3G" "" "
0OU0⎻16.66␤8.5┴0⎽0␉0T66P2E7.8689C66F3G" "" "" "" 66 10 "" "␤⎻ ⎻⎺⎼├." ≤␊⎽ "┌⎻ -⎽ -⎺┼␉ -␍▒␌⎽⎽┌␌" "" "" "" "" "" "" 0 ┼⎺ ""
"A±␊└▒─0L" "HP L▒⎽␊⎼┘␊├ (L▒┼␍⎽␌▒⎻␊)" "
1OU0⎻10␤12┴0⎽0␉3T66P2E7.8689C66F3G" "" "
1OU0⎻16.66␤8.5┴0⎽0␉0T66P2E7.8689C66F3G" "" "" "" 50 10 "" "HP LAND" ≤␊⎽ "┌⎻ -␍␍▒┴▒±␊└▒─0 -⎽" "" "" "" "" "" "" 0 ┼⎺ ""
```

Can anyone please help me to overcome this issue?

Comment: What do you get if you type `file /home/pandapx/prd_det_ROT.d` ?

Comment: prd_det_ROT.d is a dump file contains the printer setup information init. I need to see the some print queue name are present in there or not.

Comment: Yes, but it is important to see which kind of text you have inside to see if `grep` can check it properly.

Comment: /home/pandapx/prd_det_ROT.d:    ascii text

Comment: So how can we do grep cmnd on ascii text to get a proper o/p.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to extract ascii from a file that has binary data in it, use `strings` and pipe the output to `egrep`, like this

```
strings /home/pandapx/prd_det_ROT.d | egrep "acsslc|adl04085|aprsvq0|brymfghp4|brymkt02|brymkthp4|ccenaq7|davagemaq0|davb031|davipa1|davipa10042|moxipra20024|mxawhse"
```